# Inserting values into a table under conditions

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im trying to insert two values into a table if one condition is met and another is not met.

I've found a tutorial on the matter but i can't seem to get it to work.

The tutorial explains how to create a simple PHP like button, and has two tables, `articles` and `articles_likes`.

`articles` has two columns: *id* and *title*.

`articles_likes` has three columns: *id*, *user* and *article*.

The code in the tutorial looks like this:

```
$db->query("
    INSERT INTO articles_likes (user, article)
         SELECT {$_SESSION['user_id']}, {$id}
         FROM articles
         WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT id
             FROM articles
             WHERE id = {$id})
         AND NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT id
             FROM articles_likes
             WHERE user = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
             AND article = {$id})
         LIMIT 1
");
```

Now first of all, im using PDO with `$query = $pdo->prepare(" .. ");` and question marks plus `bindValue()` to avoid SQL injections, and all that is working fine with other SQL statements, but this one does not seem to work.

I've googled the `INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. FROM` syntax, and [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) explains it as copying values from one table into another one. So how is this even working in the tutorial? `articles` has a completely different structure, and he is inserting $variables into the `SELECT` statement.

Can anyone explain why this works in the first place, and how it would work in PDO?

Edit:

Here is my own code (I've added `$value` because my code is for a binary rating instead of a like):

```
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("
                INSERT INTO quote_ratings (user_ip, quote_id, value)
                    SELECT ?, ?, ?
                    FROM posts
                    WHERE EXISTS (
                        SELECT id
                        FROM posts
                        WHERE id = ?)
                    AND NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT id
                        FROM quote_ratings
                        WHERE user_ip = ?
                        AND quote_id = ?)
                    LIMIT 1
            ");
    $query->bindValue(1, $user_ip);
    $query->bindValue(2, $quote_id);
    $query->bindValue(3, $rating);
    $query->bindValue(4, $quote_id);
    $query->bindValue(5, $user_ip);
    $query->bindValue(6, $quote_id);
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: If you want help with SQL syntax, post the problematic SQL query, not the query from the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, could you also add a better problem description than "does not seem to work"?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @Andomar No, there's no error. The database just does not get updated.

Comment: Perhaps the query is working as intended?  Are you sure both the `exists` and `not exists` conditions are true?

Comment: @Andomar Yes, i've checked that. So the SQL syntax is valid so far? Should that be working?

Comment: As far as I can see it should be working yes.  If you think it's not working as it should, set up a test case at sqlfiddle.com and post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: PDO, by default, uses unbuffered queries. This for some reason makes the request impossible to parse. So the mode has to be changed for this request:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

and everything works fine from then on!

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of nested SQL queries did not get bind properly and something is left by the PDO parser during the processing of query. Also there is no way to see if the the final query generated by PDO.

I will recommend to use Mysqli library to use in such scenarios. I usually encounter such issues during complex joins or executions of custom triggers. If you want to go ahead with object oriented code you can use MySQLi Class or also you could use simple procedural approach.

Atul Jindal

Comment: Really? I thought PDO was the best and most secure solution for SQL access.. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I i completely agree that PDO is good choice to avoid sql injections but, you know at such situations you are unable to debug your queries. But if you use mysqli wisely and properly check sql injections when you input, then there will not be a problem.